# How do I call a function inside Google Sheets using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know if this is an intermittent problem, I am doing something blindingly obviously wrong, or google apps script has changed and it doesn't work anymore.

Literally all I have is the following and it's not having a bar of it

```
function main(){
  Logger.log("Hello");
}

function createMenu() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var menuEntries = [];
   menuEntries.push({name: "Test Item", functionName: "main"});

   ss.addMenu("Test Menu", menuEntries);
}
```

But all I get when I click the menu option is
[image]

What's going on, am I missing something :(

Thanks heaps

Comment: I know these kinds of answers aren't generally helpful, but your code works for me. I copied it verbatim, then set up the trigger and tested it. I didn't get any errors whatsoever.

Comment: That's incredibly weird. I've tried it with the default onOpen, creating a trigger, and in a new script file. Could it be authorization based? It's not my spreadsheet but I have authorized the script.

Comment: Maybe share a link to the test spreadsheet where it doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a confidential sheet :(

Perhaps I'll test it in a new sheet and see if it's a spreadsheet issue.

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what you did: create a test sheet and found it still didn't work.

Comment: Oh apologies, I had just created a new script file and made it a minimal case to see if something was wrong. It seems to be fine if I put it into a new spreadsheet. It works in a new spreadsheet, I wonder what the issue is :S

Comment: Did you publish the script?  What settings did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the prompt replies!

Checked it this morning (~5 mins ago) and it's working. I changed *nothing* and it now works. Very strange.

Must have been an intermittent problem, albeit for a very long period of time. Weird that I haven't seen this problem on a forum somewhere. Still have no idea what caused it but hey it's working now haha.

Bottom line: intermittent problem :(